# GridBagLayout gave me unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I have the following peice of code, I need to create a grid 15 items divided into two columns, in the 6th row, only one item will take place of 2 items.

I expect to see two columns with the same horizontal width but what I get is different, the first column take one third of the whole size while the other column takes two thirds, why this happened????

```
Insets ins = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
GridBagConstraints SymbolTextc           = new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);
GridBagConstraints SymbolLabelc          = new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0); 
GridBagConstraints ComapnyTextc          = new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);
GridBagConstraints ComapnyLabelc         = new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);
GridBagConstraints PriceTextc            = new GridBagConstraints(0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);
GridBagConstraints PriceLabelc           = new GridBagConstraints(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);
GridBagConstraints MaxQtyTextc           = new GridBagConstraints(0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);
GridBagConstraints MaxQtyLabelc          = new GridBagConstraints(1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);
GridBagConstraints PurchasePowerTextc    = new GridBagConstraints(0, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);
GridBagConstraints PurchasePowerLabelc   = new GridBagConstraints(1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);
GridBagConstraints NewCoverageTextc      = new GridBagConstraints(0, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);
GridBagConstraints NewCoverageLabelc     = new GridBagConstraints(1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);
GridBagConstraints NoteLabelc            = new GridBagConstraints(0, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);
GridBagConstraints CancelButtonc         = new GridBagConstraints(0, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,ins,0,0);
GridBagConstraints OkButtonc             = new GridBagConstraints(1, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,ins,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programmatically deal with your **x** and **y** values, like below :

```
int gridcol1 = 0;
int gridcol2 = 1;


Insets ins = new Insets(0,0,0,0);

int y=0;
GridBagConstraints SymbolTextc           = new GridBagConstraints(gridcol1, y, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);
GridBagConstraints SymbolLabelc          = new GridBagConstraints(gridcol2, y, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0); 

y++;

GridBagConstraints ComapnyTextc          = new GridBagConstraints(gridcol1, y, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);
GridBagConstraints ComapnyLabelc         = new GridBagConstraints(gridcol2, y, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);

y++;

GridBagConstraints PriceTextc            = new GridBagConstraints(gridcol1, y, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);
GridBagConstraints PriceLabelc           = new GridBagConstraints(gridcol2, y, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);

y++;

GridBagConstraints MaxQtyTextc           = new GridBagConstraints(gridcol1, y, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);
GridBagConstraints MaxQtyLabelc          = new GridBagConstraints(gridcol2, y, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);

y++;

GridBagConstraints PurchasePowerTextc    = new GridBagConstraints(gridcol1, y, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);
GridBagConstraints PurchasePowerLabelc   = new GridBagConstraints(gridcol2, y, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,ins,0,0);
```

If you do it like I have described then you will see where your problem is.

Comment: Unfortunately Oliver, The result still the same, further, there's no difference between your code and my code rather than assigning the y value to variable and increment this variable......

still I'm looking for better help.

Comment: do you get what madprogrammer gets?

Comment: please post a screenshot of what you get

Answer (score 2):

So, I put your code into a runnable example and got...

[image: GridBagLayout]

Would care to further point out what was not to your liking, maybe in the form of a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and screen shoot (of what you get and what you expect)